# Are there any sources where the phrase מְלַמְּדֵי תִינוֹקוֹת as used in Bava Basra, is interpreted to include female teachers of girls?

Tags: women, children, bava-batra

Would love examples of sources, the older the better, interpreting this phrase as potentially including female teachers of female students.

My understanding is that the Gemara is discussing men teaching boys whenever it uses this phrase.

See eg Bava Basra 8b.

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Sotah.3.4?lang=he   https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Nedarim.4.3?with=Tosafot%20Yom%20Tov&lang=he

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Nedarim.4.3?with=Tosafot%20Yom%20Tov&lang=he